# Operator Precedence in C

Tags: c, gcc, operators

Cannot explain the output of the following program. According to my knowledge the output should be 19, but running it gives me output of 20. I used gcc to compile this program.

```
int main()
{ 

    int x, y = 5;

    x = ++y + ++y + --y;
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program exploits undefined behavior. undefined as in: You can't know what will happen.

Comment: never use these kind of expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program exploits undefined behavior as you modify `y` multiple times between two sequence points (in your case, the end of the statement). If you turn on warnings with `-Wall`, your compiler is probably even going to warn you about that.

Answer (score -6):

6+7+6 = 19
so 19 will be your output

Comment: No. This is undefined behavior. Your compiler might return whatever it wants.

Comment: I suggest you test it out. My machine also gives 20 as stated in the question, but it's undefined behavior so the compiler would be within its rights to print a million or delete your hard drive.

Comment: @Kevin: What happened to nasal daemons?

Comment: @thejh Sure, those too, but I can't list all the calamities that could befall a user of undefined behavior :)